# Is the Flash really the "Fastest man alive"?

Tags: character, arrowverse, the-flash

In the series *The Flash* on CW, at the beginning of each episode's intro **Barry Allen** says "*I'm the fastest man alive*". But in each season, there was a much faster character in the show than Barry. Like *Zoom*, *Savitar* and even the *Kid Flash*.

Why are those other characters (mainly villains) faster than Barry? and How?

When there are other people faster than The Flash, then why is Barry called the **Fastest Man Alive** in that show?

Comment: Is he called that? From your question I gather he calls himself that.

Comment: Also, I think they stopped using that now.

Comment: @BCdotWEB yes, he calls himself that.

Comment: @Paulie_D when did they stopped that? Is that  " I'm the only one fast enoughto stop them" part is also removed?

Comment: @Vishwa But that wasn't my question. You claim that "Barry is called the Fastest Man Alive", but is that actually done in the show? Are other characters calling him that? I can call myself "the most handsome man alive", but that doesn't make it true. Only when others refer to me as "the most handsome man alive" you can claim that I'm called that.

Comment: I meant why "In the show" he calls himself that. its at each episode's intro

Comment: @BCdotWEB you asked "Are other characters calling him that?" , yes, as far as I've watched it, Iris called him that. may be more incidents that I've missed.

Comment: How can I downvote BCdotWEB comments ?

Comment: @Swarnveer why?

Comment: Irrelevantly trying to modify question

Comment: @Swarnveer if someone suggest an edit, and you don't want that, then you can reject the edit. Suggesting an edit takes time and effort. Editor is just trying to help improve the quality of the question. It'll be benefited by both you(if you're the one who asked it) and community. **You shouldn't downvote for personal reasons**,  Read here, *https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down*

Comment: I know this is a different film but didn't superman keep up with him?

Comment: @LogicalBranch in comics, few times. in movies/tv I'm not sure. anyway I'm pretty sure we had a question about Who will win on a race by Flash/Superman either here or SciFi SE. It had pretty damn good answers. please find it

Answer (score 7):

Major Spoilers...

Barry Allen IS the fastest man (or meta-human) alive. He falsely claims so in the beginning, not knowing there are faster characters in the show later on. He has to train as hard as he can to increase speeds to match enemies and juggle life.

Now, let's talk about Zoom, Savitar and the Kid Flash.

1. Zoom (Jay Garrick's alter ego) is from Earth-3
2. Kid Flash is Wally West (just a newbie in the ways of speed). He has lost some races against Barry Allen, whilst Barry teaches him the ways of the "speed force".
3. Last but not least, Savitar. If you're up to date on the latest episodes, you'll know that an alternate Barry Allen IS Savitar, ergo "the fastest man alive". If you argue that technically this isn't true, then that's another story...

Comment: I like your answer, but why "Zoom is from Earth" disqualifies him?

Comment: You said "Barry Allen IS the fastest man (or meta-human) alive." . but it's NOT, according to the show anyways

Comment: @madmada I've edited the answer to explain why Zoom's disqualified.  He's not from the same dimension as Barry.